# Creating a New Web Service Consumer Domino

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to import a WSDL in to my Domino Designer 9.0.1 client. I have downloaded the WSDL file and specify it in the Local File part of the wizard.

I click OK and get the error

"The requested operation failed. Server redirected too many times (20)"

I have imported other WSDL's without a problem and the only difference with the one I now need, is that I need to login to see the WSDL.

Does this stop the wizard?

If so, is the only option writing the java agent from scratch to access the data?

Obviously I cannot provide the actual wsdl I am trying to attach to as it is a paid service, so not sure what other information I can provide to help find a solution.

Thanks

Graeme

Comment: Download the WSDL file and import the downloaded file as local WSDL file.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply but that's what I said I am trying to do in the first paragraph....still doesn't work :(

Comment: Not clear: on which server is the WSDL ?
If you need to login to display the WSDL, it's logic that Domino won't be abble to SEND the data (see in the bottom of your WSDL the **location** i.e. the url the data are sent to) to the server. You need to solve this credential problem.